# Salesforce <-> Whatsapp integration

Tags: lightning, integration, case

Currently me and my team are having a demand to create an Whatsapp <-> Salesforce integration for customer service.

For example, when a client sends a message to the company's Whatsapp number, a case will be opened and the agent can reply and view messages through a Lightning Component displayed at the case page.

Is there any links or documentation that instructs how to do such development?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I think this will be more on outside of Salesforce as how your Company can re-route messages received to Salesforce and accordingly if there are APIs to accept replies from Salesforce. You may like to take a look at [this discussion](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005ZxJQAU), as I see there are some discussions around the same topic.

Comment: did you check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/